# Proving ring homomorphism between $\ell^\infty$ and $B(H)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am trying to show for a separable Hilbert space $H$ with onb $e_n$
$$\Phi: \ell^\infty \to B(H),\quad (a_n)\mapsto \left(x\mapsto \sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} a_n \langle x,e_n\rangle e_n\right)$$
is a ring homomorphism but getting stuck.

$$\Phi(1_n)(x)=\sum_n\langle x,e_n\rangle e_n=x$$
and
$$\Phi(a+b)(x)=\sum_n(a+b)_n\langle x,e_n\rangle e_n=\sum a_n\langle x,e_n\rangle e_n+\sum b_n \langle x,e_n\rangle e_n=\Phi(a)x+\Phi(b)x$$

but for multiplicativitly
$$\Phi(ab)(x)=\sum_{n}(ab)_n\langle x,e_n\rangle e_n$$
and
$$\Phi(a)\circ \Phi(b)(x)=\Phi(a)\left(\sum_nb_n \langle x,e_n\rangle e_n \right)=\sum_{m}a_m\left\langle \left(\sum_nb_n \langle x,e_n\rangle e_n \right),e_m\right\rangle e_m$$
For $n\neq m$ the scalar product is $0$, hence
$$\sum_na_n \sum_nb_n\langle x,e_n\rangle\langle e_n,e_n\rangle e_n=\sum a_n\sum b_n\langle x,e_n\rangle e_n.$$

Can I bring the series under one sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum over $n$ consists of a single term. Since $$\left\langle \left(\sum_nb_n \langle x,e_n\rangle e_n \right),e_m\right\rangle = \sum_n b_n \langle x,e_n \rangle \langle e_n,e_m \rangle = b_m \langle x,e_m \rangle$$
you get
$$\sum_{m}a_m\left\langle \left(\sum_nb_n \langle x,e_n\rangle e_n \right),e_m\right\rangle e_m = \sum_m a_m b_m \langle x,e_m \rangle e_m.$$